# Laravel Ignore with defined in Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I defined an Eloquent model in Laravel `AssessmentCategory` with a `with` relation with another Eloquent model `AssessmentQuestion`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AssessmentCategory extends Model {

    protected $table = 'assessment_categories';

    protected $with = ['questions'];

    public function scopeJsonColumns($query) {
        return $query->selectRaw('assessment_categories.id, assessment_categories.title');
    }

    public function questions() {
        return $this->hasMany(AssessmentQuestion::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

the `AssessmentCategory` now always loads its relation (child) data, but I want to call the `AssessmentCategory` somewhere without loading the relation (child) data.

```
AssessmentCategory::jsonColumns()->get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `without()` Method when want to get data without relation.

```
AssessmentCategory::without('questions')->jsonColumns()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple way to fix you problem.

1. You can disable eager loading for current query at all:

```
AssessmentCategory::setEagerLoads([])->get();
```

2. You can exclude only one relation from eager loading:

```
AssessmentCategory::without('questions')->get();
```

3. Or you can disable eager loading at all by removing:

```
protected $with = ['questions'];
```

note that in this case you need yo overwrite all previous queries.